# Objective C: How to implement a datagrid view (tables with multiple columns)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am currently working on an iPad application that uses a table view to present data, I was inspired by the iTunes application in iPad that present it's data in multiple columns in a very nice and neat manner, and the most interesting thing is that during the portrait mode the itunes application displays data in 2 columns but when the user switches to landscape mode, it switches the display to 3 columns (since there are plenty of space to display data horizontally).

This is what i'm talking about: [image: http://usingapple.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/ipad-AppStore.jpg]

but i found out that iOS SDK only supports single column for tableview (it would be nice to utilize the entire space provided on iPad screen to present data), i did some research and i found out that the best way to present data in multiple columns yet like spreadsheet style is to use datagridview instead, but iOS SDK did not provide any data grid view controls for iOS developers.

I found out over the internet some customized tables like:

- AQGridView.
- DTGridView.
- and also the one from this:
  http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html
- and the one from this:
  http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/04/14/building-editable-gridview-for-iphone-apps/

But sadly none of these ever met the requirements of the application i was working on.

Could you guys provide me some ideas or share some sample codes or links on how to display data in somehow-data grid view, to achieve similar effect used in iTunes application (as shown above).. Any form of help would be pretty much appreciated. Thank you guys!

Comment: Source code is available for all four of the implementations you mentioned. What questions do you have that aren't answered by one of those? Which requirements do these not meet? Can you tell us specifically what you don't know how to do, or should we just start guessing?

Comment: The ones that you've mentioned are a pretty complete list of options that you will find. For what it's worth, Apple uses HTML/Javascript to format the App Store pages. Like @Caleb suggested, can you elaborate on your problems?

Comment: my problem is this: i have to present data on table, data includes images, labels, texts and buttons just as what you see above. If i use table view, it only supports single column.. i need to present my data in multiple columns to be able to utilize the space provided in iPad screen.

Comment: on the AQGridView as i've searched for it, it has bugs, and it focuses only on displaying images.. on DTGridView, they did not provide details on how to implement it and like AQGridView it also has bugs, like missing data when scrolling, on the http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html, i cannot find any source code of it, it says not available, and lastly the one from this: http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/04/14/building-editable-gridview-for-iphone-apps/ just presents it's data in plain single column..

Comment: So to wrap things up, my question is simple is there anyway you can customize your table view to make it look like a datagrid? that can support portrait and landscape mode as well (display three columns on portrait then divide them into 4 columns when in landscape) Thank you guys.

Comment: I use GMGridView. See this related thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100380/ios-grid-view-with-support-for-horizontal-scrolling

Answer (score 2):

The summary answer is, place multiple data "views" across in a single cell.

The more detailed answer:

Create custom views that represent the single cells you want.  You can for this purpose make them resizable enough to work two across or three across (they will get loaded into 1/2 or 1/3 of the cells bounds).

Then make a custom UITableView cell, that can take two or three data items - load up an instance of the custom view previously created in the cell for each data item you have, placing them next to each other.  You can have the cell do the view layout when groups of data items are added.

In the cellForRow code in the table delegate/datasource, you use your data source in groups of two or three (and report the row count accordingly) to pass along to the custom cell.

Sorry I can't share code, but I have used this technique before in other applications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Would there be an issue since i am fetching my data from WCF JSON web service?, everytime the user switches orientation, the images would be downloaded and reloaded again? I understand if you can't share the codes, but could you atleast provide some screenshots of how would it look like? like in your applications, to give me broader idea and perspective on how will i do what you just said.

Comment: I can't really provide screen shots since most of the work is done in code (apart from defining the cell views).  Just imagine in your screen shot that each item is an instance of a view defined in IB.  For downloading data from a service usually you would download data into an array, and base the table off whatever was in the array - so there's no re-download as the user scrolls.  If some data is too large to download the whole table at once, download enough to get a sense of how many items are in the table, and have each cell start downloading items after a brief delay.

Comment: @JordanRodriguez -- With a table view one might be inclined to only download what fits in one screen (plus maybe a little extra), then "download on demand" as scrolling occurs.  This would mean that you'd sometimes see a "loading" icon/message in a cell (and, of course, the code would be more complex), but the initial delay to present the first screen would be minimized.

Comment: Yes, but you have to download at least enough metadata to know how many cells the table may hold...

Comment: Yes, you need to know how many cells, or at least when there's more -- you can "adjust" the number of rows as need be, after an appropriate song and dance.  But knowing the actual number is better.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with creating a UIView class to represent a single cell, and another that lays out an array of those cells in a grid? Put your grid view in a UIScrollView and you're about done.

UITableView is obviously a pretty complex class. Much of that is to make it very general, very reusable, and able to support a huge number of rows. Your class doesn't necessarily need to be that complicated -- if you have a fairly small number of cells, your "grid" could really just be a UIView in which you lay out cells in rows and columns. UITableView removes cells that aren't seen in order to save memory; you might need to do something similar if you have hundreds of cells, especially if they're large, but a few dozen probably won't require that.

In short, since you need a grid view for a particular use, you don't need to do all the extra work that would be required for a general, reusable solution.

Comment: The table view has the "advantage" of automatically managing large lists for you.  This is added work for the developer, but saves storage for large tables.  For a table with a max of maybe 25-100 lines, though (depending on cell complexity) the scroll view is likely a better choice,

Comment: It also depends on whether horizontal scrolling is desired. If the grid is wider than the screen, rolling your own view will likely be easier than trying to adapt UITableView.

Comment: This is true, though the original question didn't appear to involve 2-dimensional scrolling.

Comment: @HotLicks On the contrary -- the arrows and page indicators in the image give the impression that you can *only* scroll horizontally, which is often the case in the various App Store interfaces.

Comment: Which is still only 1-dimensional scrolling, and which I'm pretty sure you can do with a table view, if you hold your mouth right.